# Why tf.stop_gradient can't freeze variable?

Tags: tensorflow

Look at the code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1)
x = tf.stop_gradient(x)
y = 2 * x
g = tf.gradients(y, x)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    print(sess.run(g))
```

I want to freeze `x` and the gradient of `y` wrt `x` is zero, but the output is `2`, so what's wrong?

### Update

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x0 = tf.Variable(1)
x1 = tf.stop_gradient(x0)
y = 2 * x1
g = tf.gradients(y, x0)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    print(sess.run(g))
```

I use `x1` which don't overwrite `x0`, but when I run this code, it will raise a error. If `tf.stop_gradient` act as `tf.identity`, I think `x0` will have a path to `y` in computation graph and the gradient is `0` rather than raising a error? Can someone tell me what `tf.stop_gradient` does indeed?

Comment: You overwrote your original `x` with the result of stop_gradient, so when you call `tf.gradients` you are not computing the gradient wrt the variable. Use another variable to store the output of stop_gradient and you won't see this.

Comment: That's basically equivalent to my answer. `tf.stop_gradient()` acts like an identity op without a gradient definition. It's still possible to derive the gradient w.r.t. it's input but the chain rule stops at this point. Introducing a temporary variable will have the same effect as my answer. @etarion

Comment: See my update @chrert

Answer (score -1):

`tf.stop_gradient()` stops the gradient computation at the specified point in the computation graph. Applying it to the variable is "too late", but you can apply it to `y`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1)
y = tf.stop_gradient(2 * x)
g = tf.gradients(y, x)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    print(sess.run(g))
```

Note that this will not output `0` but instead throws an error, since the gradient of y w.r.t. to x is undefined in this case and you explicitly ask for it. In a real-world scenario this would probably not be the case.

Comment: This answer is obscuring the issue. There is nothing "too late" applying it to x (and the code in this answer applies it even later in the computation). And it's not mentioning the mistake that the OP made (passing the result of stop_gradient to tf.gradients).